# Unable to extend custom repository interface with spring data and mongodb repository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

User Repository interface:

```
 public interface IUserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, Long>, IUserDAO {

 }
```

User DAO Interface:

```
public interface IUserDAO {

        List<User> query(String field, String val);
}
```

User DAO implemention:

```
@Repository
@Qualifier("UserDAO")
public class UserDAO implements IUserDAO {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;


    @Override
    public List<User> query(String field, String val) {
        ....
    }

}
```

User Facade:

```
@Component
public class UsersFacade extends BaseFacade<User> implements IUsersFacade {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UsersFacade.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private IUserRepository usersRepository;



}
```

Users:

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;

    //getter 
    //setter
}
```

This is the error i get:

> Org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'usersController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'usersFacade'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'usersFacade': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'usersRepository'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'IUserRepository': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property **query** found for type User!

The above error message has been changed if i'm changing the signature in by changing the method name to query1 i'm getting:

> .... Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property **query1** found for type User!

I'm guessing that for some reason its expect to have match between the name of the filed in the users to match the name of methods.. if i'm creating filed in User.java named query, the app is starting.

What do i missing here? i would like to use the functionality of MongoRepository and add my own custom repository operations - what do i missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: You're not doing it as the documentation explains how to do it: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior

Comment: @JBNizet Hm... on your link, please check the next section
 interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>, CustomizedUserRepository

Comment: I have, so what? The doc says, in a big outlined rectangle: "The most important part of the class name that corresponds to the fragment interface is the Impl postfix.". Do you respect that rule?

Comment: Sorry, I probably missing some knowledge - you are saying that the postfix been scanned by some kind of reflection? or its just for naming convention?

Comment: I'm saying that, in order to provide custom methods for a repository, the repository interface must implement an additional interface defining those custom methods, and the class implementing this interface must have the name of the additional interface with the postfix `Impl`. And it must not be annotated with `Repository`. In short, you need to do what the documentation says you should do.

Comment: Thank you very much! it did work, could you share the explanation on how it really works? or any documentation that would remove the fog?

Comment: Well, it's just a convention that you must follow in order for spring-data to work as expected. Without such a convention, you ould need to somehow tell spring-data where the impementation of each custom interface is located.

Comment: Got it, thanks again!